# Check if URL contains text and brackets

Tags: javascript, url, contains, square-bracket

I want to check my current URL, for example:

```
http://www.dummy.com/subpageone/pagetwo.html?ineedthis[andthis]&butnotthis
```

I want an `alert` if I got exactly `ineedthis[andthis]`

So far I got

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("ineedthis") > -1) {
    alert("your url contains it");
}
```

However it's not enough. How do I check for the `[andthis]`? I have tried it with some variations but no luck at all.

```
indexOf("ineedthis\[andthis\]")
indexOf("ineedthis%5andthis%5D")
if (/ineedthis\[andthis\]/.test(window.location.href))
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `indexOf("ineedthis[andthis]")` works fine for me - returns index 45, in the example URL you gave. Also, no need to escape the square brackets.

Comment: may be you are getting encoded url with `window.location.href`. try decoding it first before comparing it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ineedthis[andthis]") > -1) {
    alert("your url contains it");
}
```

As searchValue for indexOf is string rather than regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use Regular expression to do the same:

```
(function(){

var pattern = new RegExp(/ineedthis\[andthis\]/);
alert(pattern.test('ineedthis[andthis]'));

}());
```